# Convert Php Curl to MAgento2 Curl

Tags: magento2, curl

I have created this code but now I want to convert this code to magento2 curl library

```
             $ch = curl_init(); 
            //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form- 
             urlencoded'));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
            curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code ..

```
<?php
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    ) {
        $this->curlFactory = $curlFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }
     
    
    public function callPostAPI() {
     $dynamicUrl = $apiUrl . '?' . http_build_query($query);
     $httpAdapter = $this->curlFactory->create();
     $httpAdapter->write(
         \Zend_Http_Client::GET,
         $dynamicUrl,
         '1.1',
        ['Content-type: application/x-www-form- urlencoded']
    );
   $response = $httpAdapter->read();
   $body = \Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response);
   $response = json_decode($body);
   print_r($response);
    
    ?>
```